# keras error when using custom loss

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I was to use a simple BiLSTM model with my own custom loss function in Keras.
See below.

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(1,8)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax'))

def my_loss_np(y_true, y_pred):

    labels = [np.argmax(y_pred[i]) for i in range(y_pred.shape[1])]

    loss = np.mean(labels)
    return loss

import keras.backend as K
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = K.eval(my_loss_np(K.eval(y_true), K.eval(y_pred)))
    return loss
```

When I compile this model, I get an error -

```python
model.compile(loss=my_loss, optimizer='adam')

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_95_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
     [[Node: dense_95_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: you can't use eval in a loss function.

Comment: Thanks. This is my first time writing a loss function. Can you please tell me how I can write the loss function if I want to use numpy?

Comment: You can't use numpy, you have to use the functions in keras.backend, or tensorflow/theano directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here with your loss function:

1. You are using NumPy on tensors, unfortunately though it is an intuitive this doesn't work. You need to use tensor operators from the [Keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/), they are very similar.
2. To that end you are calling `K.eval` but at this stage you are still constructing a *symbolic* computation graph which will be run in TensorFlow or Theano. So the tensors don't have a value to compute per say, you need to keep it symbolic, you can get any values like you do in NumPy.
3. Even if you fix the problems above, you are using a non-differentiable operation `argmax` which will not work with gradient descent algorithms.

Your model looks like a multi-label classification problem, 20 classes as your final layer is 20 with softmax. In this case, the literature uses `categorical-crossentropy` loss to train the classifier network.